# CURL multipart form post - HTTP error before end of send, stop sending

Tags: linux, curl, multipartform-data

I am sending a multipart form POST via CURL from Linux shell script. The request works fine in Postman but from CURL it fails with:

```
Internal Server Error
```

then

```
HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
```

I even copy the Curl for Linux Shell code directly from Postman and paste into the shell script, so it should be exactly the same request that Postman is making.

Here is the command:

```
curl --request POST \
  --no-alpn \
  --url https://XXXXXXXXXXX/api/v1.0/XXXXX/XXXXXX/XXXXX \
  --header 'accept: text/plain' \
  --header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  --header 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  --header 'sessionid: $session_id' \
  --form filename=XXXXXX.zip \
  --form XXXXXX=XXXXXX \
  --form file=@$file_path \
  --trace-ascii /dev/stdout || exit $?
}
```

And here is the log from --trace-ascii:

```
https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/api/v1.0/XXXXXX/XXXXX/XXXXXXXXX
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0== Info:   Trying XXX.XXX.XXX.XXXX...
== Info: Connected to XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com (XX.XX.XX.XX) port 443 (#0)
== Info: found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
== Info: found 592 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
== Info: SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
== Info:     server certificate verification OK
== Info:     server certificate status verification SKIPPED
== Info:     common name: *.XXXXXX.com (matched)
== Info:     server certificate expiration date OK
== Info:     server certificate activation date OK
== Info:     certificate public key: RSA
== Info:     certificate version: #3
== Info:     subject: OU=Domain Control Validated,CN=*.XXXXXX.com
== Info:     start date: Mon, 15 Aug 2016 08:23:38 GMT
== Info:     expire date: Thu, 15 Aug 2019 08:23:38 GMT
== Info:     issuer: C=US,ST=Arizona,L=Scottsdale,O=GoDaddy.com\, Inc.,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
== Info:     compression: NULL
=> Send header, 363 bytes (0x16b)
0000: POST /XXXXX/api/v1.0/XXXXXX/upload/XXXXXX HTTP/1.1
003b: Host: XXXXXX.XXXXXXX.com
0059: User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
0072: accept: text/plain
0086: cache-control: no-cache
009f: sessionid: $session_id
00b7: Content-Length: 1639
00cd: Expect: 100-continue
00e3: content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBounda
0123: ry7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW; boundary=------------------------b059847fb557
0163: a899
0169: 
<= Recv header, 23 bytes (0x17)
0000: HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
=> Send data, 387 bytes (0x183)
0000: --------------------------b059847fb557a899
002c: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"
005d: 
005f: xxxxxxxxxx.zip
006b: --------------------------b059847fb557a899
0097: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="XXXXXXXXXXX"
00cc: 
00ce: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
00ea: --------------------------b059847fb557a899
0116: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="XXXXXX.zip
0156: "
0159: Content-Type: application/octet-stream
0181: 
=> Send data, 1204 bytes (0x4b4)
0000: PK........r~.K..D!....p.......output/XXXXXXX.XXXXX.....7Z..7Zux...
0040: ............{LSW....@.!`.9. F..Eh+.......JA..W.2.V...A.%>... #Q1
0080: T.....{Nb.]&..1.3M|.........w..z.]8..I.I>.....n?...\hM/.h..?oy^.
00c0: ..... ..:.>J..Q...N...*A...l`...."..N...@.P'........d..._.....L
0100: .].......z....N6.B......Y5t...Zd.V...}..l...........EC..$..e...W
0140: .V`.lV...p..d._.....S...............d`.l..}.....f[...{....`....M
0180: .....kN..[.4.2w.9.bN....q.8.'.K.......'..~........sI.....K...s.
01c0: ...U.'..d,.......>......T.5....|.$,)o'bIy{...pN.....K.o..[..cWp.
0200: c.@..B.S........d.I..P./.F..0....=4.......d..#{K$..#.^=.......
0240: *....Bi...i....8j!T......|.Ld...x....>......A...|.I.}>.....Yt=..
0280: ..Tp.q...O&.. .....Ac..V....a......f.G...!x.f.i.gu}.2i.4....NK..
02c0: .G;..k~......=*....g..c#..c.M.oW........-...vW.~#u...#....cz.bu=
0300: .."Bs.js\.z.1.....&|.MV..<a"4...IqRO.kKC.v.Gz.....].G.\.|...:om
0340: .C.v5G..X].kw..\....R/.........C.X].5<.B.\'....z.O|@.v.P\......
0380: ^...f~........9....YG~fum}....^,K.......F.vmIl....hI."h.FM.....f
03c0: ....Z...`um.}E...1;......_....yF.xV...BDh...U..z...*.o.`O..V.W.6
0400: ..kf.n...*.{..].].c~.w~K......4I.k.Y.....r.wV.................F
0440: .v..O..OPK..........r~.K..D!....p.....................output/xxxxxxx
.mldUT.....7Zux.............PK..........V...H.....
=> Send data, 48 bytes (0x30)
0000: 
0002: --------------------------b059847fb557a899--
<= Recv header, 36 bytes (0x24)
0000: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
<= Recv header, 15 bytes (0xf)
0000: Server: nginx
<= Recv header, 37 bytes (0x25)
0000: Date: Mon, 18 Dec 2017 15:15:56 GMT
<= Recv header, 26 bytes (0x1a)
0000: Content-Type: text/plain
<= Recv header, 28 bytes (0x1c)
0000: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<= Recv header, 24 bytes (0x18)
0000: Connection: keep-alive

100  1639    0     0  100  1639      0   2269 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2266<= Recv header, 29 bytes (0x1d)
0000: X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
<= Recv header, 83 bytes (0x53)
0000: Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX; Path=/;
0040:  Secure; HttpOnly
== Info: HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
<= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: 
<= Recv data, 106 bytes (0x6a)
0000: 64
0004: <ErrorResponse><key/><localizedMessage/><httpError>Internal Serv
0044: er Error</httpError></ErrorResponse>
<= Recv data, 5 bytes (0x5)
0000: 0
0003:
```

I should add that the CURL command is being run from a Docker container.

Comment: Explain how this is not programming. Because it is a Linux shell script? Its being called by Python code embedded within YML.

Comment: Adding "... in a script" is not compelling. When the problem is reduced to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), its just a question on how to run the cURL command; or why the server is crashing. My apologies if I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my particular case the problem was that I was sending session ID surrounded in double quotes, so the server failed to parse as a number, threw an exception and rejected the request. Had to get hold of the server logs to figure that out.

Reason session ID was in double quotes was because earlier on in the code, I was setting the session ID using:

```
someJson | jq '.sessionId'
```

If you do this, jq will return the result in double quotes. To get the value without the double quotes, use:

```
someJson | jq -r '.sessionId'
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem in you curl command : `$session_id` have single quotes around, so the variable will never be evaluated.

"Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words